# How to publish a .Net Core Web Api and Angular 6 app from VS Code to Azure?

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made an application in VS code. This application is having both .NET Core WEB API and Angular 6 solutions. So my question is how to deploy both solutions using VScode to azure. I installed Azure Extension.

Thanks.

Comment: just google it! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: this blogs outlines every step of the way on how to do it https://medium.com/@omikolaj1/complete-guide-to-deploying-angular-and-asp-net-33a0976d0ec1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the article like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-deployment-of-contact-application-using-asp-net-core-web-api-angular-6-0/) to Deploy ASP.NET Core Web API, Angular 6 Using Visual Studio Code.

As you have said, open the visual studio code, go to the Extensions and search Azure extension.
Select Azure Extension Pack and install it.